# IIS vs httpZip (or other product) Compression

Tags: compression, iis, iis-7

We're currently comparing httpZip compression software.  Has anyone used this and can offer a comparison between that product and IIS?  Is there a big savings for httpZip over IIS?  If you aren't using httpZip, I'd love to hear an alternative product comparison too...